# Error installing node.js

Tags: software-installation, nodejs, 19.10

I'm trying to install node.js version 12 on my Ubuntu 19.10 laptop by following the instructions [here](https://www.fosstechnix.com/install-latest-node-js-and-npm-on-ubuntu/).

When I execute the curl command I get an error about a locked directory:

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 12.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
Error executing command, exiting
```

I've looked to see if there's an `apt-get` task and rebooted my machine, but no joy.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get past this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Permission denied"* usually means you're not root. But you always need superuser rights to install software.

Try this:

```
> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash -
```

Notice the `| sudo bash` command at the end. That will run the install script as root.

Comment: Exactly right.  Thank you so much!  I'm still learning Ubuntu.  Your expertise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's something I tend to forget myself. In time you get used to it: Ah  "Permission denied" I probably forgot sudo... ;)